# Calculate accuracy of model created with Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am using a logistic regression method to predict the outcome of my dataset and want to know how the accuracy is calculated

Code:

table(test$get_admission,predictTest >= 0.5)

Output: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to asses the accuracy of a logistic regression model on a dataset.

I think what you've posted is a "Confusion Matrix", which shows the true positives, true negatives, false positives, and false negatives of model predictions on a test dataset. Confusion matrices are (basically) built by having a set of "test" data that you didn't use to train your model, for which you know the actual values, and running your model on the inputs of the test dataset, and measuring the discrepancy between the actual and predicted (the output of your model) values. Here's an article on measuring the accuracy of models in general: https://clevertap.com/blog/the-best-metric-to-measure-accuracy-of-classification-models/

This article cover some methods of evaluating logistic models in R: https://www.r-bloggers.com/evaluating-logistic-regression-models/

There is not enough information about your data to recommend anything in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy is calculated like this: (True Positives + True Negatives)/(True Positives + True Negatives + False Positives + False Negatives)

This is how you could do it (second last row):

```
test <- c()
test$get_admission <- c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 80))

predictTest <- c(rep(0, 1), rep(0.6, 99))

confusion <- table(test$get_admission, predictTest >= 0.5)
confusion

accuracy <- (confusion[2, 2] + confusion[1, 1]) / sum(confusion)
accuracy
```